# How can I demonstrate $f(g(x))=h(x)$ implies $f(x)=h(g^{-1}(x))$ taking all it to be bijective

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I'd actually like to demonstrate it not proof that is using algebra to get $f(x)=h(g^{-1}(x))$  and not verifying $f(g(x))=h(x)$ by $f(x)=h(g^{-1}(x))$

I've tried:

$f.g=h$

$(f.g).g^{-1}=h.g^{-1}$

$f=h.g^{-1}$

I'm almost sure that's right but I'd like to demonstrate it in terms of $f(x), g(x), h(x)$ notation and when I try that so it gets confusing for me, see below:

$f(g(x))=h(x)$

$f(g(g^{-1}(x)))=h(g^{-1}(x))$

$f(x)=h(g^{-1}(x))$

to be more clean I'm not sure if row 1 to row 2 step is correct it sounds kinda weird for me because $x=g^{-1}(x)$ doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: You cannot prove this because it is wrong.

Comment: $f(g(x))=h(x)$ yields $g(x) = f^{-1}(h(x))$ and $f(y) = h(g^{-1}(y))$, but not the one you propose.

Comment: sorry kavi, I've fixed it out

Comment: GEdgar I tried this one too but I need proof in $x$ terms you proof just holds for $y$.

Comment: Suppose $A \stackrel g\to B \stackrel f\to C$, and $f \circ g = h$. This latter equation means that $f(g(x))=h(x)$ **holds for every $x$ in** $A$, and you want to prove that $f(x)=h(g^{-1}(x))$ **holds for every $x$ in $B$**. Indeed, if you pick $x$ in $B$, then $g^{-1}(x)$ is in $A$, and so we know that $f(g(\color{red}{g^{-1}(x)})) = h(\color{red}{g^{-1}(x)})$ holds, which is the same as $f(x)=h(g^{-1}(x))$.

Comment: By the way, for a function $f$, it is not true that $f(x)$ is another notation for it, this is just the value of the function $f$ at the point $x$ (which is in its domain).

Comment: Sorry I cant get you notation Does that mean $g: A \rightarrow B$ and $f: B \rightarrow C$?, I know that $f$ and $f(x)$ aren't the same $f$ is the math process and $f(x)$ this process evaluated at $x$ but this difference is worthless for this problem and that's a long discussion so I summary all this as another notation.

Comment: @GEdgar Sorry, your proof actually holds because all it is injective,  so if $x \in A$ then $y \in A$ as $g(x) \in A$.

Comment: Where $A \stackrel g\to B \stackrel f\to C$,  I used $x$ for any element of $A$ and $y$ for any element of $B$.